# MySQL: how to kill a user lock held by a terminated thread

Tags: mysql, locking, mysql-8.0

We're using MySQL 8.0.32 hosted by AWS RDS.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| version       | 8.0.32 |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.19 sec)
```

I'm beholding a mystery, and would love any suggestions for how understand it.

### What we believed happened

Client code executes `get_lock`, and obtains a named lock. Later, the client dies (we assume). However, the lock isn't released.

### What we can observe

The lock exists and is granted:

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks where object_type = 'USER LEVEL LOCK' and object_name = SHA2('STACK_PROD-1026110_SSE_METRICS_SCHEDULER', 256)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          OBJECT_TYPE: USER LEVEL LOCK
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: NULL
          OBJECT_NAME: e0bb94c74f7c0eb170c5d797067b5305d8009a2ec5b816cbf9b240b8968ca235
          COLUMN_NAME: NULL
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 70382713694640
            LOCK_TYPE: EXCLUSIVE
        LOCK_DURATION: EXPLICIT
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
               SOURCE: item_func.cc:5355
      OWNER_THREAD_ID: 7541234
       OWNER_EVENT_ID: 1084
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

However, the thread with ID = 7541234 no longer exists:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.processlist where ID = 7541234 ;
Empty set (0.06 sec)
```

To confirm, the lock is definitely held, despite that thread not existing:

```
mysql> select IS_FREE_LOCK('e0bb94c74f7c0eb170c5d797067b5305d8009a2ec5b816cbf9b240b8968ca235') ;
```

### What we've tried

The thread can't be killed, because it doesn't exist:

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_kill(7541234);
ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 7541234
```

This doesn't effect the status of the lock - i.e. this query continues to return false:

```
mysql> select IS_FREE_LOCK('e0bb94c74f7c0eb170c5d797067b5305d8009a2ec5b816cbf9b240b8968ca235') ;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IS_FREE_LOCK('e0bb94c74f7c0eb170c5d797067b5305d8009a2ec5b816cbf9b240b8968ca235') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                0 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We have reason to believe this has actually happened more than once in the last week.

1. Any ideas for what could be causing a user lock (i.e. made using the `GET_LOCK()` function call) to persist past the time the thread holding it dies?
2. Is there any way to release it now short of restarting the DB?